# Quantum and CPU time wasting

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, cpu, scheduling, scheduler

I've heard that if a thread does not consume the entire **time-slice** allocated by the **OS's thread-scheduler** the remainder is wasted: e.g. if the time-slice is 10ms and the thread ends before 5ms, the remaining 5ms are lost.

So if you have a lot of small fast tasks always taking less time than the originally allocated time-slice the waste can be important system-wide.

If this is true I guess with standard workloads the impact is negligible and will be a concern only with specific use-cases like servers running a single type of tasks.

Do you confirm this?

Have you more information?

Comment: I think the answer **highly** depends on the _OS_, _development environment_ and _development methodology_. I'm pretty sure that if you forcefully return the control to the task scheduler (like calling `Sleep(n, True);` or `WaitFor*Object()`) it won't waste machine time. I can Imagine you don't have an opportunity to do so in higher level environments, so you have to rely on compiler optimization, but I know no such use case. _Also I think milliseconds are at least 1-2 magnitudes more time than we should talk about in this case._

Comment: Also note, that initiating a thread is an expensive procedure, so if you have lots of small tasks, you can lose a lot of machine time scheduling a task for each one but not because of the flaw of the task scheduler but because of that cost. I think even if there is a loss in scheduled time, the thread creation cost is at least a magnitude more.

Comment: @mg30rg Thanks for putting things in perspective, indeed thread management overhead can be an important issue. And for more context we were talking about Windows NT. (so not the most up-to-date OS :))

Comment: 'I've heard that if a thread does not consume the entire time-slice allocated by the OS's thread-scheduler the remainder is waste' - OK, where did you hear that?

Comment: In that case I would suggest to use Thread pools. **AFAIK** - and I'm not sure since I didn't work under **NT** for quite a long time - thread pools were available on **NT** too, and they help you solving thread management overhead issues.

Comment: 'initiating a thread is an expensive procedure' - depends on what you mean.  Other factors being equal, and given a free core to run the thread, creating a thread typically requires ~250us.  Signaling an existing thread takes ~5us.

Comment: @MartinJames It was at work from one of my colleagues, so I don't have any source document to share. Thanks for the figures on the "overhead", I'll preciously keep them in mind and bookmarked. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've heard that if a thread does not consume the entire time-slice
>   allocated by the OS's thread-scheduler the remainder is wasted

I don't think that's the case. For linux a running task goes into terminated state when it exits, thus freeing the processor:

[image: Linux process states]

---

> ... but if the OS's scheduler only "wakes up" at fixed times (e.g. with a
>   frequency of 10ms/100 times per second)

The scheduler is invoked whenever a task needs to be scheduled. That happens when the time allocated for the running task has expired (that doesn't necessary mean fix frequency), but also on IO/events, exit and other scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes it frees the processor but if the OS's scheduler only "wakes up" at fixed times (e.g. with a frequency of 10ms/100 times per second) to redispatch threads on cores the current core would not be used in the meantime waiting for the scheduler decisions, except I guess for handling some interruptions which don't depend on the OS. But yes that seems strange to me, hence my question requesting clarifications. :)

Comment: @Pragmateek the scheduler is invoked whenever a task needs to be scheduled. That happens when the time allocated to the running task has expired (that doesn't necessary means fix frequency), but also on IO/events, exit and other scenarios.

Comment: Thanks, that seems perfectly logical.